# Which US airport has the lowest circling MDH?

Tags: airport, circling-approach, terps

As I recently contemplated [14 CFR 135.223](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=a0eb2fc492b00f026a59c9ddc4d480a4&mc=true&node=se14.3.135_1223&rgn=div8) and its implications, I began wondering about airports with exceptionally low circling minima.

---

For a little context and background, the part of §135.223 that sparked my imagination is the following exemption clause:

> (1) The ceiling will be at least 1,500 feet above the lowest circling approach MDA

This got me thinking along these lines: "*How often might one encounter both a circling MDH sufficiently low as to allow exemption from the fuel requirements of §135.223(a) and a ceiling high enough that the requirement of §91.169 to file an alternate airport remained in effect? Such a scenario would require a reported or forecast ceiling of 1900 ft and a circling MDH of 400 ft or less.*

I know that there are at least a few airports with MDH of 400 ft or lower (which seems altogether *too* low). Thus, my question is:

**Which airport in the United States has the lowest published circling Minimum Descent Height (MDH) for an instrument approach?**

I initially wanted to apply this question equally to any airport worldwide. However, I have chosen to limit the scope of this question for two reasons.

Firstly, ICAO standards are more strict in this area than the TERPS standards that the US, Canada, and a few other parts of the world adhere to. Specifically, the TERPS standards for Cat A prescribe a minimum MDH of 350 ft, while ICAO prescribes a higher minimum of 394 ft.

Secondly, I recognize that discovering an ultimate answer to this question (i.e., "ABCD airport definitively has the lowest circling MDH") is difficult, especially if the question's scope included airports from multiple nations. For this reason, I have chosen to limit the scope of the question to the United States of America, where available databases should provide an opportunity for a definitive answer.

---

For example, the lowest MDH that I know of is [Point Hope (PHO/PAPO)](https://skyvector.com/airport/PHO/Point-Hope-Airport) with a circling MDH of **361 ft** for both the RNAV RWY 1 and RNAV RWY 19.

[image]

While this *might* be the lowest published MDH, I don't know whether or not it is.

I am looking for any answer that can factually establish which airport has the lowest published circling MDH, whether that might be Point Hope or some other airport.

Comment: If your only approach was a circling approach with a 1200' MDA, would 2000/3 get you out of needing an alternate, or in that case would you need an alternate with anything below a 2700' ceiling?

Comment: @RalphJ I.a.w. §91.169, given an IAP at the first airport of intended landing, and given a forecast of 2000/3 or greater, no alternate need be filed, regardless of IAP minima. I.a.w. §135.223, given a circling MDH of 1200, and given weather of 2000/3, sufficient fuel to fly to the alternate must be carried. That's what the regs say. I know, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Part 135 operation is not part 91 operation. If you are a pilot in the USA you should know that basic difference. 
A 135 operator would need 2700' ceiling to avoid planning an alternate if he CMDA is 1200.

Comment: Part of the problem is that most new approaches use an "assumed adverse obstacle" of 200feet above all terrain, because towers of 199ft do not need to be registered and there are many new cell towers erected each year.(also they don't need to survey every tree) The required obstacle clearance for circling is 300feet, plus the 200ft AAO = 500ft minimum unless some other factor comes in like land that is easy to visually survey for new towers and low potential for new trees, oil derricks or wind turbines in surrounding waters or land. Cat D and E min circling HAA is 550ft

Comment: @max §135 operations are still subject to §91 regulations in addition to the §135 regulations. §135 itself does not explicitly stated when an alternate need be filed.

Comment: J Walters Mostly incorrect. All IFR flights are required to file an alternate as default. Not planning an alt is considered an exception to the rule, and is only applied if the flight and operation can meet specific conditions, those conditions are different for 91 and 135. (135.223(b)) True that 135 does not explicitly state the alt must be *filed* before starting the flight or as part of the original flight plan, but it is implied by both the need to have it planned for fuel and because you need a clearance to the alt. 135/121 use op-specs, these can allow exceptions to 91.

Comment: @Max No, the need for an alternate is determined by both 91 and 135, as well as the operator's manual, and is not required by default but depending on forecasts. My company gives the conditions in which an alternate is required when I fly 135 flights, and these requirements are in accordance with 91 and 135 both. Do you have any experience operating under FAA 135 regulations?

Comment: Aa black and white fact, I have the regs in font of me, and plenty of specific education to properly read them, I also know how op-specs are developed and approved for 119 operators in general. The 135 reg overrides the 91 regs(just by being more restrictive) and an op-spec can override either, a POH has no bearing on this. As written an alt is always required as the default for IFR flight planning; not including an alt on an IFR plan is an exception only allowed for certain conditions. That you often have those qualifying exceptions does not mean that the exceptions become the default.

Comment: @Max I don't know where the POH comes in. By operator's manual I refer to the Air Carrier/Operator's manual as required by regulation (e.g., see §135.21). I believe you are arguing semantics (that an alternate is "always" required, except where not) and I am content to disagree with you and leave you to that on your own. The material point which I wished to emphasis is that §91 does apply as well to §135 operations. Our company's FAA accepted requirements for filing an alternate are derived from §91 for our §135 operations.

Comment: I took "operator's manual" as a pilots or aircraft operator's manual. I have always lumped the operator's manual you are talking about under the umbrella of "op-specs". My point is similar to yours in that there is a hierarchy to 135/121, 91, and op specs; I differ as not all 135 operations use your company's op specs and 135 covers alt. planning requirement. As for semantics, they literally determin the meaning of a statement, so yes in legal matters one is always arguing semantics. Which situation is the default matters when in a situation that has not been explicitly [or clearly] covered.

Comment: Ok, I see some of your confusion.The operator is required to have a manual distinct from the OpsSpecs that covers far more operational items. The Ops Specs are a defined list of operations for which an operator is or is not authorized. Each Ops Spec starts as a generic template with variances in detail for which the operator is authorized. The full scope of Ops Specs is available in the FSIMS. Re: semantics, the regulatory default is that you are not allowed to do anything, unless otherwise authorized. Talking about defaults is not helpful here where the situations have been clearly covered.

Comment: @MaxPower Another important distinction is that the Ops Specs are approved, while the manual is only accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to partially answer this question. According to TERPS Section 2-7-1(b),

> the minimum ROC in the circling approach OEA is 300 feet. Adjustments
> must be applied as specified in paragraph 3-2-2.c.

OEA means Obstacle Evaluation Area, and ROC means Required Obstacle Clearance.

However, according to TERPS table 3-2-1 the minimum HAA (Height Above Airport) is 350 feet for CAT A aircraft.

If you look at the example given in TERPS Section 2-7 -1(c), it shows that the higher of the CMDA is published. Either 300 ft above the an obstacle located within the OEA, OR 350 ft above the airport. The 623 + 300 = 923 which rounds to 940. However, the 600 airport elevation + 350 = 950, but according to TERPS that rounds to 960. So 960 is published. The 960 is equal to a height of 360 ft AGL.

The way that I interpret this is that the lowest possible circling minimum descent altitude would be 360 ft above the airport assuming there are no obstacles in the OEA. However, the lowest circling height I've ever seen is around 440 AGL somewhere in New Mexico.  The obstacles are almost always going to dictate the minimum height unless there is an airport on a an elevation with no buildings or antennas nearby.

So, if you find an airport with a circling minimum height of 360 AGL, that is likely the airport with the lowest (or tied for the lowest) circling minimum in the US. The airport you found (Point Hope) at 361AGL is likely one of the lowest if not the lowest in the US.

Comment: This is a great way to answer the question on how low it can actually be.